# Webscraping with python: information incomplete, hided by togostanza framework

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

Thank you all in advance. I am a newbie to webscraping and stackoverflow. I tried to scrape some biodata from https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/G00055MO.

The links I want to scrab are from a table

[image]

The outerHTML code is

```
<a href="http://identifiers.org/pubmed/7503987" target="_blank">7503987</a>
```

Looks like it is embedded in "togostanza" framework.

[image]

I tried two different ways to find the link but the HTML code I get is incomplete.
The methods I tried are attached here:

Method 1:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html

class Render(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()
a=r"https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/G00055MO"

_glycan1= Render(a)
_result_glycan = _glycan1.frame.toHtml()
# print(_result_glycan)_formatted_result = 
str(_result_glycan.encode('utf-8'))
# print(_formatted_result)
_tree = html.fromstring(_formatted_result)
# print(_tree)
_archive_links = _tree.xpath('//a/@href')
print(_archive_links)
```

This method returns a link list that doesn't have the link I am looking for.

Method 2:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/G00055MO")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='literature']/togostanza-literature//main/ul/li/ul/li[1]")
```

This method cannot find the xpath I fed in.

Can anybody help me find out the alternative way to fetch the data? I do appreciate.

Thanks,
Bokan

----Closed----
Thank you all for helping me reformat the question. This is really first post on stackoverflow!

I tried my second method with PhantomJS and Firefox driver. Finally, the firefix webdriver works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be [this internal API](https://ts.glytoucan.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20bibo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fontology%2Fbibo%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20glycan%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.jp%2Fbio%2F12%2Fglyco%2Fglycan%23%3E%0APREFIX%20glytoucan%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.glytoucan.org%2Fglyco%2Fowl%2Fglytoucan%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ffrom%20%3Fpartner_url%20%3Fdescription%20%3Fpubmed_id%20%3Fpubmed_url%0AWHERE%7B%0A%09VALUES%20%3FaccNum%20%7B%22G00055MO%22%7D%0A%09%3Fsaccharide%20%20glytoucan%3Ahas_primary_id%20%3FaccNum%20.%0A%0A%09GRAPH%20%3Fgraph%20%7B%0A%09%09%3Fsaccharide%20dcterms%3Areferences%20%3Farticle%20.%0A%09%09%3Farticle%20a%20bibo%3AArticle%20.%0A%09%09%3Farticle%20dcterms%3Aidentifier%20%3Fpubmed_id%20.%0A%09%09%3Farticle%20rdfs%3AseeAlso%20%3Fpubmed_url%20.%0A%09%7D%0A%09%3Fgraph%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ffrom%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fgraph%20rdfs%3AseeAlso%20%3Fpartner_url.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fgraph%20dcterms%3Adescription%20%3Fdescription.%0A%7D%20ORDER%20by%20%3Ffrom%0A) that is being called by JS. The input parameter is an urlencoded [sparql](/questions/tagged/sparql) query like the following :

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
PREFIX glycan: <http://purl.jp/bio/12/glyco/glycan#>
PREFIX glytoucan: <http://www.glytoucan.org/glyco/owl/glytoucan#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?from ?partner_url ?description ?pubmed_id ?pubmed_url
WHERE{
    VALUES ?accNum {"G00055MO"}
    ?saccharide  glytoucan:has_primary_id ?accNum .

    GRAPH ?graph {
        ?saccharide dcterms:references ?article .
        ?article a bibo:Article .
        ?article dcterms:identifier ?pubmed_id .
        ?article rdfs:seeAlso ?pubmed_url .
    }
    ?graph rdfs:label ?from .
    OPTIONAL {?graph rdfs:seeAlso ?partner_url.}
    ?graph dcterms:description ?description.
} ORDER by ?from
```

Using the following will get your links :

```
import requests

query = """
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
PREFIX glycan: <http://purl.jp/bio/12/glyco/glycan#>
PREFIX glytoucan: <http://www.glytoucan.org/glyco/owl/glytoucan#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?from ?partner_url ?description ?pubmed_id ?pubmed_url
WHERE{
    VALUES ?accNum {"G00055MO"}
    ?saccharide  glytoucan:has_primary_id ?accNum .

    GRAPH ?graph {
        ?saccharide dcterms:references ?article .
        ?article a bibo:Article .
        ?article dcterms:identifier ?pubmed_id .
        ?article rdfs:seeAlso ?pubmed_url .
    }
    ?graph rdfs:label ?from .
    OPTIONAL {?graph rdfs:seeAlso ?partner_url.}
    ?graph dcterms:description ?description.
} ORDER by ?from
"""

headers = {'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json'}
payload = {'query': query}

r = requests.get('https://ts.glytoucan.org/sparql', params=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
data = r.json()
links = [ t["pubmed_url"]["value"] for t in data["results"]["bindings"] ]
print(links)
```

Comment: You are so profession! Could you show me how can I get the URL-encoded query information showed above? I only find the query information from http://code.glytoucan.org/rdf-ontology/rdf-doc.html#motif. But I haven't learned this data query method before, any background information would be helpful!

Comment: @BokanBao the url encoded query is already linked in the above post when you click on internal API (too long for comments)

Comment: Note that you can view the full query in Chrome console, open console go to network tab (maybe refresh page) and add filter `sparql` to see all those internal api call

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the driver to Firefox that solves the problem. However, I am very interested in how to query the database by using the sparql language!